# magento 2 custom module is not listing in admin panel

Tags: magento2, module

after `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` module is not listed. where is my mistake?

File location are

**app/code/Test/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "test/banners",
    "description": "Test Banner For test",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Test\\Banners\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Test/registration.php**

```
  <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Banners',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Test/Banners/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Banners" setup_version="2.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you enabled it (  bin/magento module:enable  Test_Banners ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your edit I see that you're listing files (registration.php and composer.json) outside the module's directory.
The correct path for these file should be:

```
app/code/Test/Banners/registration.php

app/code/Test/Banners/composer.json

app/code/Test/Banners/etc/module.xml
```

after making these changes run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command

Comment: simple mistake :(

Answer (score 2):

Its not app/code/Test/Banners/etc/config.xml

It is `app/code/Test/Banners/etc/module.xml`

Comment: sorry typo mistake. still have fever of magento 1 :P

Comment: Its working fine.Please check permission.

Comment: which version you test it still not luck..

Comment: I have tested it in magento 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

plz replace below code to your `composer.json` file,

```
{
    "name": "test/magento2-banners",
    "description": "Test Banner For test",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
 "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Test/Banners"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Remove var folder and type setup command,
Its working fine.

Comment: after change still not working

Comment: still same not working

Comment: which error are display in cmd?

Comment: no error in command

Comment: you have to check for app/etc/config.php file, for Test_Banners => 1 entry or not?

Comment: no entry for that